# Responsive Multi Image Size Layouts?

Tags: jquery, css, image, layout

I’m unsure if this is the right place to be asking this but i’m trying to figure out how to establish a layout which has multiple image sizes but as well as keeping it responsive.

[image]

The images feed in a a list from a cms as well e.g…

```
<ul>
                        <li> <img src="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li> <img src="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li> <img src="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li> <img src="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li> <img src="" alt="" /></li>
                    </ul>
```

I’ve played around with css but is too restrictive, i’m assuming a JS avenue is the way to go, but not seen anything..

Thank you and apologies if this is the wrong section

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image auto resize to the max width of the boundary by using max-width:100% and height:auto.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The above responsive image CSS works on IE7 and IE9, but doesn't work on IE8. To fix it, add width:auto. You may apply a conditional CSS specifically for IE8 or use the IE hack below:

```
@media \0screen {
  img { 
    width: auto; /* for ie 8 */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darkagelink however, this doesn’t solve the problem that it could be all large images, or all small images it needs to adjust automatically?